# A question about reading and calculating thermal resistance of a voltage regulator from its datasheet

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I have this [voltage regulator](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf)  from [this supplier](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/linear-voltage-regulators/5338209/) and the exact model name is given as: "LM317T/NOPB".

I plan to use this circuit to power a windwane's potentiometer which is around 10 kΩ:

[image]

As you see I want to set the excitation voltage for the vane pot to around 9 or 10 V where the op-amp will be supplied directly from a 12 V switch-mode power supply. For this purpose I will use an LM317 to obtain 9 or 10 V for the vane excitation, so I will set the LM317 for 9 or 10 VDC.

I will mount the vane in a box around 50 m high which will stay there for at least 3 months.

Since I will use a linear voltage regulator I decided to find out whether I need a heatsink.

I have encountered two challenges which I put here as questions:

1. In the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf), when I check the thermal resistances, I can't figure out which model I should use:
   [image]
   Mine is T0-220, but in the datasheet there are two types namely KCT and KCS, but my model is "LM317T/NOPB", and on it it is written "LM317T +P". So should I use the thermal resistance for KCT or KCS?
2. Here is how I calculate the ΔT:
   ΔT = θJA × P
   In my case:
   P = V<sup>2</sup> / R = 10<sup>2</sup> / 10000 = 0.01 W
   But for junction to ambient temperature I used to use the following:
   Junction to Ambient = Junction to Case + Case to Ambient
   But in the datasheet there is no Case to Ambient but there is Junction to Ambient. Does "Junction to Ambient" already include "Case to Ambient"? Should I in my case only use Junction to Ambient? If so, in my case ΔT becomes like 4°C, and I conclude I don't need heatsink. Did I calculate correctly and does the duration (three months) matter when it comes to using a heatsink?

Comment: With a 10k pot, the LM317 only needs to source 1 mA. So its power consumption is only 2 mW. You're way over-thinking this.

Comment: If the part you bought actually has the National Semi logo on it, that means its been sitting around in RS's stockroom for at least 5 years. If you were using enough power to actually care about the answer to this question, it would be better to buy new parts so you can get a datasheet that actually corresponds to your part.

Comment: Is my using thermal resistance using only "Junction to ambient" (θJA) is enough ?

Comment: And where in the datasheet I can find out the minimum input voltage needed for this regulator to output 10V? Thanks

Comment: Yes but be careful to understand what conditions they assumed when measuring that value. For some SMT parts they might assume a very large copper area on the board dedicated to heat-sinking the part, for example.

Comment: If you have multiple questions, ask them with multiple posts. But search first to see if the question has already been asked. (Hint: the term to search for is "drop-out voltage")

Answer (score 1):

You have calculated the power dissipated in the wind gauge - what you need to know is the power dissipated in the LM317.  The wind vane will draw 1 mA, and you have 3 volts across the LM317, for a power dissipation of 3 mW due to the load. However, the LM317 requires a minimum load current of 5 mA for proper operation - the voltage-setting resistors are usually selected to draw that current.

With 1 mA for the wind gauge, and 5 mA for the LM317 operation, the LM317 will dissipate about 6 mW - no need for any heat sink at such a low power.  You could use a TO-92 packaged LM317 without concern.

Comment: Oh thanks I understand now. But couple of things 1-) Where did you find 5mA in the datasheet? In datasheet at 6.3 in Recommended Operating Conditions min output current is 10mA 2-) So as thermal resistance using only "Junction to ambient" (θJA) is enough right? thanks in advance

Comment: The TI datasheet shows "Minimum load current to maintain regulation" with a typical value of 3.5 mA, and maximum of 10 mA. I got the 5 mA figure out of my head - but it is reasonable.  My answer doesn't really answer the calculation question, but does show the power dissipation is so low that there's no need to worry about heatsinking.

Comment: The circuit has the voltage-setting resistors missing, also the important input and output capacitors are missing, all are shown in the datasheet.